# sonar.exclusions property not recognising * or ** values for windows machine

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

This is my directory structure

E:/Jenkins/workspace/dev_A/src/github.com/ABC/A/

```
E:
|-- Jenkins
|    |--workspace
|    |   |--dev_A
│    |   |   |--src   
│    |   |   |   |--github.com
│    │   |   |   |   |--ABC
│    │   |   |   |   |  |--A
│    │   |   |   |   |  |  |--X
│    │   |   |   |   |  |  |--Y
│    │   |   |   |   |  |  |--vendor
|    |   |   |   |   |  |  |--static-analysis.xml
```

this is my jenkins job I have written:

```
sonar.projectBaseDir="E:/Jenkins/workspace/dev_A/src/github.com/ABC/A/"
sonar.sourceEncoding="UTF-8"
sonar.projectKey=A
sonar.projectName=A
sonar.projectVersion=${BUILD_NUMBER}
sonar.golint.reportPath="E:/Jenkins/workspace/dev_A/src/github.com/ABC/A/static-analysis.xml"
sonar.coverage.reportPath="coverage.xml"
sonar.exclusions= **/vendor/**
sonar.sources=.
sonar.sources.inclusions=**/*.go*
```

When I execute the job I am getting the following error:

ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
ERROR: Illegal char <*> at index 0: **/vendor/**

Can someone please help me in finding the correct syntax?

Comment: try giving full path to exclusions; E:/Jenkins/workspace/dev_A/src/github.com/ABC/A/vendor/**

Comment: using your full path approach, for each and every project I will have to manually give the path for exclusions. So, I want a generic solution which will work on each and every project.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
**/vendor/**/*
```

As suggested in https://docs.sonarqube.org/7.4/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/